# How do I match words in different languages

Tags: python

How can I write a regular expression to efficiently match both Swedish and English words?

I must be able to match the likes of Å, é and '. I think 123 is also a word. I even think 1:e and 1st are words...

How would I proceed if I wish to match words from Russian and Japanese also.

Thanks,

Barry

P.S. The following are not words and should not be matched:

, =HELLO=, @NEW_LINE_MARKER, can"t, hel*o, /new/

Also,

This string "Hey! What? Yes, I'm coming." should be split into:

(Hey, 
What, 
Yes I'm coming)

Comment: If those are words, then what aren't words?

Comment: soo .. everything is a word? `s.split()`

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel: please post that as an answer so that it can get all the upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

> Japanese

Detecting word boundaries in CJK texts requires knowledge of the language at a fluent level;  These texts are not written with any sort of word separation, and lack a distinct structure in written form that distinguishes one word from the next.  [More on the subject.](http://www.jstor.org/pss/488773)

Roman texts (English, Swedish) and most Cyrillic texts (Russian), are divided on whitespace and certain punctuation (period, comma, dash, but not hyphen).